# Multitenant application - access for users who do not belong to a specific tenat eg: Customers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

I'm working on a multitenant project management application in ruby on rails and am a bit bogged down with implementing access for users who might not belong to a specific tenant.

For example we have the users Bob and Martha and they belong to a tenant A - alternatively there are two other users namely Jim and Jill who belong to Tenant B. Now we have a client called Mark who is a client to both tenants. Both tenants have projects and I need to build in an accessible form for the client so the client can sign in and view his projects. The thing is that I don't want and obviously no client would want a seperate login for each tenant here. I'm interested in coding the tenant management by myself here however I'm a bit bogged down on how to implement this.

I'm implementing row based tenancy i.e every model would have a reference to the tenant model here and signed in users can edit and add whatever belongs to their tenant. However with respect to a client or a possible case of a consultant user who might require access to more than one tenant - how do I set up the structure here.

Ideally a client would want to be able to sign in and view a list of all projects differed by tenant/company. How can I set up this structure? Also I want to keep this open ended such that it is possible that a user from TenantB might also be a client to TenantA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The thing is that I don't want and obviously no client would want a seperate login for each tenant here.

They actually do want this, mainly for legal, auditing or security reasons.

Multi-tenancy exactly means the separation of data. So during login or right after that you choose a tenant. After that you only see data exactly of this tenant. There is no break-out later: It's possible to *switch* to another tenant, but not to *merge* data of different tenants.

If this is not what you want, consider to redesign your data model: There could be assignments between projects and persons. Customers can have their "own" projects by having a foreign key in projects linking back to the customer. This data model approach differs from using a multi-tenancy approach which is actually a technical means to separate data on row or instance level.

Comment: Hmmm this actually makes sense as currently the tenancy model seems to be an excessive overhead. I've notcied even basecamp seems to have transparently moved away from the subdomain based tenant model - or maybe I'm assuming. I'll go with what you've stated and formulate a different model design - thanks.

Comment: @Ali and Beryllium - any clues on the model design you've opted for? i have the same problem: guests might need to access the same resources as tenant A, and tenant B. any ideas?